# list to dataframe without unique columns

Tags: r, list, datatable, datatables

I have this loop to generate some values

```
for (j in 1:2)  {
  table <- rep(data.frame( 
    matrix(c(letters[1:2], 
             sample(c(rep(1,100),0), size = 1),
             sample(c(rep(0,100),1), size = 1)),  ncol = 2) ), j)
}
```

I would like to get this output like this

```
X1 X2
a  1
b  0
a  1
b  1
```

To get table of letters with one column and numbers in second column

I tried

```
do.call(rbind, table)
data.frame(matrix(unlist(table), nrow=length(table), byrow=TRUE))
```

But I am not able to get values to right column in data table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `table` is getting updated in each of the iteration.  Instead, we may use `replicate` to create a `list`

```
lst1 <- replicate(2,  data.frame( 
    matrix(c(letters[1:2], 
             sample(c(rep(1,100),0), size = 1),
             sample(c(rep(0,100),1), size = 1)),  ncol = 2) ), simplify = FALSE)
do.call(rbind, lst1)
```